# Searching for elements of a struct using pointers C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, stdstring

okay so the title is pretty self-explanatory, but the best thing would be to look at the code; ignore the names of the variables btw.

my create and list functions work just fine, here they are:

```
struct obras {
std::string nome[10];
std::string autor[10];
std::string ano[10];
std::string price[10];
}OBRA[10];
int counter=0;
struct obras *ptr=OBRA;



void inserir(struct obras *ptr) {   //CREATE
    system("CLS");

    printf("Insira o nome do autor da obra:\n");
    scanf("%s", ptr->autor);

    printf("\nInsira o nome da obra:\n");
    scanf("%s",ptr->nome);

    printf("\nInsira o ano em que foi feita a obra:\n");
    scanf("%s",ptr->ano);

    printf("\nInsira o preco da obra:\n");
    scanf("%s",ptr->price);

    return;
}



void inserir(struct obras *ptr) {
    system("CLS");

    printf("Insira o nome do autor da obra:\n");
    scanf("%s", ptr->autor);

    printf("\nInsira o nome da obra:\n");
    scanf("%s",ptr->nome);

    printf("\nInsira o ano em que foi feita a obra:\n");
    scanf("%s",ptr->ano);

    printf("\nInsira o preco da obra:\n");
    scanf("%s",ptr->price);

    return;
}
```

and this is my attempt at searching:

```
void pesquisar_autor(struct obras *ptr) {
            int k;
            std::string proc[10];
            system("CLS");
            printf("Insira o nome do autor:\n");
            scanf("%s\n");

            for (k=0;k<counter;k++) {
                if (ptr[k].autor==proc[10]) {
                    printf("\nOBRA %i:\n",k);
                    printf("Autor: %s\n", ptr[k].autor);
                    printf("Nome da obra: %s\n", ptr[k].nome);
                    printf("Ano em que foi feita a obra: %s\n", ptr[k].ano);
                    printf("Preco da obra: %s\n\n", ptr[k].price);
                }
            }
            system("PAUSE");
}
```

please help, i need to sleep guys!!

EDIT::OKAY so the need to sleep is getting to me... here is the declaration of the search function, i know it's wrong but i have no clue whqt to do next:

```
                                    if (option==1) {
                                            pesquisar_obra(OBRA);
                                            system("PAUSE");
                                    }
```

Comment: Your structure variables are all *arrays of `std::string`* which is probably not what you want. I suspect you either want to make them just `std::string` or else make then *arrays of char* as in: `char nome[10]`.

Comment: if (ptr[k].autor==proc[10])  when I try to compare these two (i changed all my struct variables to char example[10] and the variable proc as well), i get the following error:
ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]|

Comment: The title is not self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think `if (ptr[k].autor==proc[10])` will work? You declared `std::string proc[10];` and never assign it.

**EDIT:**

In `if (ptr[k].autor==proc[10])`, `autor` is `char[]`, and `proc[10]` is `char`, that is different, `char[]` is an array of `char`.

In C, you can declare `char proc[10]`, and use `scanf` to read data, finally use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare these two string, you can't use `==`.

In C++, the better way is to declare all the variables in your struct as `std::string`, and use `cin` to read input data. Also, `proc` should be `std::string` as well(use `cin`), and finally, you can use `==` to compare these two strings.

Glad to help.

Comment: my bad... scanf("%s\n",proc[10]);

Comment: And, if you declared `std::string proc[10]`, it means you can use `proc[0]` to `proc[9]`, you can't use `proc[10]`, it is out of the array index.

Comment: error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'std::string {aka class std::basic_string<char>}' through '...'|

Comment: |error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::string [10] {aka std::basic_string<char> [10]}' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')|

Comment: these are the error logs I'm getting... appreciate your replies I'm kinda desperate... so should I create a bigger std::stringproc[]? I really have no clue, I just need to compare that input with the contents on my struct

Comment: I think you should get to know the difference between `char` and `std::string` first, like the comment above said.

Comment: I tried using scanf the same way I used it in the "inserir"(insert) function, I usually use cin>>, only looking for a solution